# Photoshop Graphics Processor Settings window not detecting my device

Tags: graphics-card, adobe-photoshop, nvidia-geforce

I've noticed that my installation of PhotShop isn't able to handle advanced graphics processing (most of the options are simply greyed out.)

After a bit of Googling, I found that you need to ensure you have the right device selected, and allow advanced processing, in the Performance tab of the Preferences window.

When I go to this tab on my installation it hasn't detected a device, and the options are greyed out.

I've followed a number of tutorials, [including this one.](http://tricky-photoshop.com/photoshop-is-not-detecting-graphic-card/#comment-19923)

As advised, I've updated my graphics card and Photoshop. The option for the preferred device isn't available in my Nvidia Control Panel, but I've set CUDA GPUs to point directly at the card.

None of this has made any difference.

- Windows 10 pro
- Photoshop 2017 Creative Cloud (2017.1.1 20140425.r.252 x64)
- Nvidea GTX-1070 (382.05)

[image: Missing device]

[image: Device settings]

Comment: Have you confirmed that Photoshop specifically supports that GTX 1070 for graphical acceleration?

Comment: You indicate your using "PhotoshopCC" but what version/build?  "Photoshop CC" or version 14, which was released 4 years ago, is very unlikely to support a GTX 1070.   Try CC 2017 and see if it works

Comment: Ah, sorry. Yeah, it's CC 2017. The newest version, on subscription, downloaded from Creative Cloud. I'll check their supported devices list now, thanks :)

Comment: So update your question.  What driver version do you have installed?

Comment: Sorry, got called away. Updated